# An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. even after adding secret_key_base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I have set the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` environment variable, but I'm still getting the error mentioned above.

I tried two different ways to solve it but the result was same.

config/secrets.yml

```
production:
   secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: `2017-03-02 08:52:48 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET / }
#<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>`